# Assign a Function Argument with a Loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, arguments

I have an array of list items in a piece of Javascript code. I would like to assign an onclick event handler to each one. Each handler would be the same function, but with a different input argument. Right now I have:

```
function contentfill(i) {
    box = document.getElementById("text");
    box.style.background="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
    var content = new Array();
    contentdivs = document.querySelectorAll("#contentfill>div");
    box.innerHTML = contentdivs[i].innerHTML;
}
li[3].onclick = function() {contentfill(0);};
li[4].onclick = function() {contentfill(1);};
li[5].onclick = function() {contentfill(2);};
```

This works well enough, but I would like to achieve the same thing with a loop, for example:

```
for(i=3;i<=5;i++) {
    j=i-3;
    li[i].onclick = function() {contentfill(j);};
}
```

This, however, does not work. Since j seems to be defined as 2 at the end of the loop, each time I click, it only seems to call contentfill(2).

Answer (score 3):

For an alternative approach, consider having each of the elements aware of what argument it should be using.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var el = li[i + 3];
    el.dataset.contentIndex = i;
    el.addEventListener('click', contentfill);
}
```

Then `contentfill` would have to extract the argument from `.dataset` instead of taking an argument, of course.  (This is the same mechanism as jQuery's `$.data`.)

I tend to prefer this since (a) it doesn't generate tons of tiny wrappers, (b) it allows me to later examine and possibly change the "arguments", and (c) it lets me predefine them in the document using `data-` attributes.  Effectively changes them from function arguments into behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `i - 3` should be bound to the click handler function; a closure can provide this functionality:

```
li[i].onclick = (function(j) {
    return function() {
        contentfill(j);
    }
)(i - 3));
```

Btw, it's better practice to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) or [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) to register click handlers.